Decode Program data: and extract transaction amount
I'm trying to follow a transaction but can't seem to find a way to parse the base58 encoded data.
I'm using python, and I've tried using a code I found in another questions, but can't get it.
This is the base58 string, for reference:
vdt/007mYe4s6mkVsPpqsIwyyNTUVXZI3nMIkKQWTBVEyKiFQKKPz4GWmAAAAAAApS66hAgAAAABqoxylouMQd0K5EATmY+Sggu4dj0C8gXF7KqtUVjP3bcEbWVnAAAAAH7wLNcVAAAAMA3cZxo4AQB+RAnbDgAAADB1yRuJOQAA
def decode_transaction_data(base58_data):
    buffer = base58.b58decode(base58_data)
    buffer = buffer[8:]
    mint = buffer[0:32]
    sol_amount = int.from_bytes(buffer[40:48], "little")
    token_amount = int.from_bytes(buffer[48:56], "little")
    is_buy = bool(buffer[56])
    user = buffer[57:89]
    timestamp = int.from_bytes(buffer[89:97], "little", signed=True)
    virtual_sol_reserves = int.from_bytes(buffer[97:105], "little")
    virtual_token_reserves = int.from_bytes(buffer[105:113], "little")
    real_sol_reserves = int.from_bytes(buffer[113:121], "little")
    real_token_reserves = int.from_bytes(buffer[121:129], "little")

    mint_base58 = base58.b58encode(mint).decode()
    user_base58 = base58.b58encode(user).decode()

    ddata = {
        "mint": mint_base58,
        "sol_amount": sol_amount,
        "token_amount": token_amount,
        "is_buy": is_buy,
        "user": user_base58,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "virtual_sol_reserves": virtual_sol_reserves,
        "virtual_token_reserves": virtual_token_reserves,
        "real_sol_reserves": real_sol_reserves,
        "real_token_reserves": real_token_reserves,
    }
    for key, value in ddata.items():
        print(f"{key}: {value}")
    return ddata

Returned data is totally invalid, for example:
mint: 71xnte28VDgRRv6xJk8WaXEPiaGgJZ7CKvwiy2iaD1Vp
sol_amount: 6289053104583953233
token_amount: 4702111234474983789
is_buy: True
user: 6bpnWtxTBEp9Pn1JKXqCNnQcBCio235DZh8YX9Nmd3MQ
timestamp: 4054137323069404519
virtual_sol_reserves: 6157671158386153575
virtual_token_reserves: 7081175262528825942
real_sol_reserves: 4702111234477938263
real_token_reserves: 4708059648403912520

What am I missing? How can I extract transaction value from the base58 string?

The first 8 bytes buffer = buffer[8:] which you discard are the function hash, then the instruction data follows next, so the mint would be the NEXT 32 bytes
    mint = buffer[8:40]

and so forth...

thank you for your reply, but apparently this does not work. it decodes this vdt/007mYe6lzMKp/tTMK9A+6BGByK+C4TINPW6rACd72hGBeq4KTx2WaBgAAAAAPiyqxFQCAAABVJA1/lPXvzZY+ftshPPOrpOr9lEq9h/PlYX8T+pnNu7o5WZnAAAAAKVPwb4QAAAAEM4dxxKXAQClo53CCQAAABA2C3uBmAAA mint as 4CF3Z6649XoCfTpAsvvcY5VMKPTkFtNV9NwSSuiJvQRX while the actual mint is CADMxKWn5Vxy8f1Xnh8PGuYKhasN1jqM99J94PFVpump

I don't think slash and plus are valid base58 chars anyways, so that's probably not the base58 string.
